# How to change default country in input type='tel'

Tags: html, input

I am creating an input field type tel and this type always giving me the US as a default result i want to change it to Netherland for example,

Is it possible to do it directly?

```
<input name="phone" type="tel" id="phone" required="required" class="form-group padding-inputs" autocomplete="off" data-intl-tel-input-id="0">
```

Is there anyway to set the default country to something different then the us ? and thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use pattern validation as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/tel). As far as I am aware there is no other method.

Quote from MDN:

> As we've touched on before, it's quite difficult to provide a
>   one-size-fits-all client-side validation solution for phone numbers.

A regex example for dutch phone numbers can be found [here](https://regexr.com/3aevr).